# Is it possible to kill a RAS connection which won't disconnect

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

I have a Windows 2003 Server which has a number or RAS Connections to some of our customers. Occasionally the connections go into a mode where there are connected, but not working. Disconnecting and reconnecting solves the problem. However sometimes you can not disconnect as I get the following error message

> It is not possible to disconnect at this time. The connection is currently busy with a connect or disconnect operation.

There are no visible connection dialog boxes when this message occurs and I usually end up having to restart the server which obviously affects all the other users.

I know that if you have a service that is stuck 'stopping' you can just kill it. Is there anything similar that you can do to reset a ras connection?

Answer (score 0):

Stopping and restarting the "Routing and Remote Access" service will yield the same net affect as restarting the entire server without its broader impact.

Comment: That service is not running on my server, which is used to connect out to other sites, not for incoming connections.

Comment: Have you tried the "Remote Access Connection Manager" service? If you are local on the machine (or if it is a secondary NIC), you should also be able to disable and re-enabling the NIC connection. only users/applications on active sessions are affected, if there are no recovery capabilities.

Comment: With "Remote Access Connection Manager" the stop/start/pause and resume options are all disabled.

Comment: Is disabling and re-enabling the network connection an option? The following Microsoft KB Article might be remotely related to your situation - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237288.